# Removing and Adding Characters to a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was wondering if it is possible to remove the first 2 numbers from 8200001 and then chance it to 90 instead in **ONE** formula?

```
Example

8200001 = 9000001 
5822581 = 9022581
9688888 = 9088888
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `REPLACE` function is perfect here:

```
=REPLACE(A1,1,2,90)
```

`1` is where to start from (the position in your string)
`2` is the number of digits to replace
`90` is what to replace them with

This returns a string, so if you want a number add `--` before the function:

```
=--REPLACE(A1,1,2,90)
```

Comment: This worked great. Thank you! I appreciate you explaining the code as well.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use MID to parse:

```
=--(90&MID(A1,3,LEN(A1)))
```

Comment: I tried this and it gives a number to calculate with after: =VALUE("90"&MID(C17,3,10))

Comment: @SolarMike the `--` does the same with less typing.

Comment: seen that, about to play, ta very much